# DataList is outside the table

Tags: asp.net, datalist

I want to put a DataList in table but my DataList shows outside the table... I don't understand why.

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder2" Runat="Server">
    <table class="four_tile_table" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
                RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatColumns="2" CellPadding="0">
            </asp:DataList>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</asp:Content>
```

I have the same behavior with the ContentPlaceHolder in my MasterPage, if I put it inside a table, it shows outside.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try wrapping the `<asp:DataList>` with a `<td></td>`

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure what do you mean by you are seeing it outside the table. But onething is you are missing

> < td>

tags in your table layout.